# JavaScript to php using AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to send the score of an application to the database using AJAX.

Here is the application code

```
var score=count;

$.ajax({            
    url: 'ajax.php',            
    type: 'get',            
    data: {score: score},
    success : function(data)
    {
        alert("Succeed");
    }

});
```

ajax.php

```
<?php

$score= isset($_POST['score'])? $_POST['score'] : '';  

echo $score; 
$query=mysql_connect("localhost","admin","");
mysql_select_db("fypdb",$query); 
$sqlqury="insert into fypdbtable (score)values('". $_POST['$score']."') where username=($_SESSION['sess_firstname'])");

?>
```

I want to send the variable score using AJAX to ajax.php and then to fypdb database in `fypdbtable`.

Comment: ajax sends a get request while the php side expects post. Also please read up on safe database queries. You're using a deprecated database api and you are vulnerable to sql injection.

Comment: SHould be `fypdbtable (score) values (`

Comment: Aside from what @JimL already mentioned (GET request, but POST expected), I would disagree with the fact that the code is vulnerable to injections: *there is no actual call to `mysql_query`* (which you *shouldn't* use, as he pointed out, already). You're assigning a value to a variable, but the query isn't executed. Did you miss that in providing your code here, or is the *actual* script missing that call, too?

Answer (score -2):

In your Ajax code you're setting the type to 'GET' and in your PHP code you're using 'POST'

Use 'GET' or 'POST' in both

Comment: No working, i tried only get AND only POST without good results. I realise that variable never passes to ajax.php